# OpenGL / GLUT - lots of undefined references

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glut, freeglut

I've started with OpenGL with GLUT in C++ (MinGW). I've tried lots of GLUT files but currently, I'm using [these files](https://web.cs.wpi.edu/~gogo/courses/mingw/). I've followed all the instructions it said but I'm still getting these error (see output).

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<GL/glut.h>
#include<dos.h> // i know I shouldn't be using this

void render(void);
void keyboard(unsigned char c, int x, int y);
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(10, 10);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("Parmu Game Engine (Yes I didn't think of a better name.)");

//    glutClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glutDisplayFunc(render);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);

    glutMainLoop();
}

void render(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); // ORIGIN AT  CENTRE
        glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
        glVertex2f(0.3, 0.1);
        glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
        glVertex2f(0.8, 0.1);
        glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
        glVertex2f(0.5, 0.5);
    glEnd();

  //  glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void keyboard(unsigned char c, int x, int y)
{
    if(c == 'q')
        exit(0);
}
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if(button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON)
        exit(0);
}
```

This the output when run from cmd:

```
E:\Workspace_CPP\Atom\Parmu_Game_Engine>g++ main.cpp
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp/ccMBcaaa.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `__glutInitWithExit@12'
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp/ccMBcaaa.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `__glutCreateWindowWithExit@8'
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp/ccMBcaaa.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `__glutCreateMenuWithExit@8'
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp/ccMBcaaa.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xaf): undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode@4'
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp/ccMBcaaa.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xc6): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowPosition@8'
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp/ccMBcaaa.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xdd): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowSize@8'
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp/ccMBcaaa.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xfb): undefined reference to `glutDisplayFunc@4'
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp/ccMBcaaa.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x10a): undefined reference to `glutKeyboardFunc@4'
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp/ccMBcaaa.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x119): undefined reference to `glutMouseFunc@4'
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp/ccMBcaaa.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x121): undefined reference to `glutMainLoop@0'
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp/ccMBcaaa.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x13a): undefined reference to `glClear@4'
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp/ccMBcaaa.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x149): undefined reference to `glBegin@4'
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp/ccMBcaaa.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x16b): undefined reference to `glColor3f@12'
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp/ccMBcaaa.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x184): undefined reference to `glVertex2f@8'
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp/ccMBcaaa.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1a6): undefined reference to `glColor3f@12'
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp/ccMBcaaa.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1bf): undefined reference to `glVertex2f@8'
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp/ccMBcaaa.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1e1): undefined reference to `glColor3f@12'
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp/ccMBcaaa.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1fa): undefined reference to `glVertex2f@8'
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp/ccMBcaaa.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x202): undefined reference to `glEnd@0'
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp/ccMBcaaa.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x207): undefined reference to `glutSwapBuffers@0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It should be noted that I've not used any IDE for my code. I used atom to code and cmd to run.

I have already included E:/mingw/bin in PATH.

These are the commands I've tried:

```
E:\Workspace_CPP\Atom\Parmu_Game_Engine>g++ main.cpp

E:\Workspace_CPP\Atom\Parmu_Game_Engine>g++ main.cpp -lglut

E:\Workspace_CPP\Atom\Parmu_Game_Engine>g++ main.cpp -lglut -lGLU
E:\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lGLU
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

E:\Workspace_CPP\Atom\Parmu_Game_Engine>g++ main.cpp -lglut -lGLU - lGL
g++: lGL: No such file or directory
g++: -E or -x required when input is from standard input

E:\Workspace_CPP\Atom\Parmu_Game_Engine>g++ main.cpp -m32

E:\Workspace_CPP\Atom\Parmu_Game_Engine>g++ -c main.cpp -lglut32win
g++: -lglut32win: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

Comment: See https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/MinGW

Comment: It worked man. Thanks. You could submit this as an answer too so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/MinGW), the correct libraries to link with are

- opengl32.lib - import library for Windows OpenGL APIs (use `-lopengl32`).
- glu32.lib - import library for the Windows implementation of GLU (use `-lglu32`).
- The GLUT library does not come with Windows, so it depends on where you obtained GLUT for Windows from. In the version in the [link](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/MinGW), you need to link with glut32.lib, and make sure to include glut32.dll with your application.